Return to NZ due to OZ changed Rules, is it worth it at age 59?
Left NZ in 2000 for Aus, been working since and my husband until 2019.
It’s now 2024 and we are considering returning to NZ after being away since 2000. I am 59, turning 60 in early 2025, still working in my own business. My husband not able to work and turning 64 in February. We are dual citizens.
Where do we seek advice about pension rules regs and super transfer do’s and don’ts?
Why are we considering the change? Australian changes to the pension means I am unlikely to be able to access support until 70, currently 67 for me, and they proposed every two years it will raise a further 6months…
There is also a requirement to work for 5years once moved to access Nz pension. I am working here (Oz) would that count?

There is some information and contact details for help on the NZ government website

You might also ask at [Money.SE].  I don't spend much time there, but it seems to be rather more active you you're more likely to attract the attention of someone who can be helpful.
